# Neural network, unspecified size of input

Tags: neural-network

I'm currently trying to use some images from the Sun dataset, with varying shapes, around (1000, 400, 1). Since they are varying in shape, my approach to it was to create a numpy array with numpy arrays in it, so that I dont have to define any shape of it. What I want to do is to train a basic CNN using these pictures. The problem is, I dont think my CNN understands how my input data is defined really. In my implementation, self.X_train[0] for example contains one image (with correspondsing target in self.Y_train[0] and so on). My code right now is looking like:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Conv2D, Flatten

class network:
    def __init__(self):
        self.X_train, self.Y_train = self.generate_targets()


    def generate_targets(self):
        path = 'C:\\Users\\joaki\\PycharmProjects\\project\\project dl\\'
        folder = os.fsencode(path)
        targets = []
        inputs = []
        for file in os.listdir(folder):
            filename = os.fsdecode(file)
            if filename.endswith(('.jpg')):
                img = Image.open(filename).convert('RGB')
                img2 = Image.open(filename).convert('L')
                arr2 = np.array(img2)
                arr2 = arr2.reshape((arr2.shape[0], arr2.shape[1], 1))
                inputs.append(arr2)
                arr = np.array(img)
                targets.append(arr)
        Y = np.array(targets)
        X = np.array(inputs)
        return X, Y

    def plotting(self, type):
        plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
        for i in range(self.X_train.shape[0]):
            plt.subplot(2, 2, i+1)
            if type == 'targets':
                lum_img = self.Y_train[i][:, :, :] #[:,:,:] för färg
                plt.imshow(lum_img)
            if type == 'inputs':
                lum_img = self.X_train[i][:, :, 0]  # [:,:,:] för färg
                plt.imshow(lum_img)
        plt.show()

    def train_network(self):
        model = Sequential()
        # add model layers
        model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape = (None, None, 1)))
        model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Flatten())
        model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
        model.fit(self.X_train, self.Y_train, batch_size = 1, validation_data=(self.X_train, self.Y_train), epochs=3)




network1 = network()
#network1.plotting('inputs')
network1.train_network()
#print(network1.X_train[0].shape)
```

Is there solution to this problem, if so, can someone provide information or a source that I should follow? Thanks in advance!